# Ruby: undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass error message

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to load some data from a csv file into my program and get the following error message: **undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass error message**

Here is my code:

```
def load_students
    file = File.open("students.csv", "r")
    file.readlines.each do | line |
        name, cohort = line.chomp.split(",")
        @students << ({:name => name, :cohort => cohort.to_sym})
    end
    file.close
end
```

`@students` refers to an empty array.

Any idea what the issue is?

Thanks!

Comment: The error message is equivalent to the following one, "The receiver of `<<`, which is `nil`, does not have a method `<<`:NilClass error message". That tells you that `@students` (which you expected to be an empty array) is in fact `nil`, pinpointing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `@students` refers to an empty array.

Does it? (Apparently not, because the error message says it's `nil`!!) You never showed us where this variable get initialised.

In ruby, all instance variables evaluate to `nil` by default, if you don't define them as something else.

Comment: Got it! My array was getting initialized in another method, which I guess wasn't called early enough. Moved it outside this method and it's all good now. Thank you!